# Prove $\operatorname{Hom}(R/I, R/J) = 0$ if $I$ and $J$ are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I,J$ ideals of $R$ such that $I+J=R$. I want to prove that $\operatorname{Hom}(R/I,R/J)=0$.

I have a few ideas but can't quite pull it together. I don't know if I am seeing the notation $I+J=R$ correctly, but am doubting if we need that $I \cap J = \emptyset$.

**Idea 1:** $R/I=\{ r + I : r\in R\} = \{i+j +I : i\in I, j \in J\} = \{j +I : j \in J\}$.

And $R/J=\{ r + J : r\in R\} = \{i'+j' +J : i'\in I, j' \in J\} = \{i' +J : i' \in I\}$.

So it seems intuitive that the only homomorphism from $\{j +I : j \in J\}$ to $\{i' +J : i' \in I\}$ is the zero-homomorphism. But I don't see how to show that.

**Idea 2:** We use that $\operatorname{Hom}(R/I,R/J) \cong \{ f \in \operatorname{Hom}(R,R/J) : I \subset \ker(f) \}$. Then we have $$\{ f \in \operatorname{Hom}(R,R/J) : I \subset \ker(f) \} = \{ f \in \operatorname{Hom}(R,R/J) : \text{$f(a) = 0$ for all $a \in I$} \}$$ Then writing $I \ni a=r-j$ for some $r,j\in R,J$ we get $f(r-j)=0 \implies f(r)=f(j)$. Then this shows that $f=0$.

I would greatly appreciate any insight. This is not a homework question or anything graded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f\colon R\to R/J$ such that $f(I)=0$. Writing $1=i+j$ with $i\in I$ and $j\in J$, we have $f(1)=f(j)=jf(1)=0$. So $f=0$.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $1=i+j$ with $i\in I$ and $j\in J$.

Then $f(1+I) = f(j+I) = s+J$ for some $s\in R$ and also $f(1+I) = jf(1+I) = j (s+J)$.

Thus $s+J = js + J$ and so  $s-js\in J$. Since $j\in J$, it follows that $js\in J$ and so $s\in J$.

Thus $f(1+I)= s+J = 0+J$ and hence $f$ is the 0-mapping.